# Unhandled event loop exception when I open a JSP file in eclipse helios

Tags: eclipse, jsp, exception, tomcat5.5, eclipse-3.6

I want to generate Crystal Reports in Eclipse for which I have recently downloaded crystal reports 2.0 for eclipse. I am using eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32 (3.6) version and Tomcat v5.5 server version.

I can generate the JSP file from the Crystal Report file(.rpt) as shown [in this PDF](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/3020847c-6064-2b10-e5be-fcd27295fc16?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&32804960207401). But the problem is when I open it. It cannot be opened by any editor except Text Editor.

On opening with other editors gives me following Error:

**`Message:`**

> Unhandled event loop exception

**`Exception Stack Trace:`**

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui.internal.contentassist.JSPStructuredContentAssistProcessor.setAutoActivationDelay(I)V
>   at org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui.internal.contentassist.JSPStructuredContentAssistProcessor.updateAutoActivationDelay(JSPStructuredContentAssistProcessor.java:114)
>   at org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui.internal.contentassist.JSPStructuredContentAssistProcessor.(JSPStructuredContentAssistProcessor.java:73)
>   at org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui.StructuredTextViewerConfigurationJSP.getContentAssistProcessors(StructuredTextViewerConfigurationJSP.java:189)
>   at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextViewerConfiguration.getContentAssistant(StructuredTextViewerConfiguration.java:291)
>   at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.StructuredTextViewer.configure(StructuredTextViewer.java:215)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.createPartControl(AbstractTextEditor.java:3250)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.createPartControl(StatusTextEditor.java:53)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.createPartControl(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:432)
>   at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.createPartControl(StructuredTextEditor.java:1507)
>   at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.ui.common.sash.SashEditorPart.addPage(SashEditorPart.java:110)
>   at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.editors.HTMLEditor$3.createPages(HTMLEditor.java:266)
>   at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.ui.common.sash.SashEditorPart.createPartControl(SashEditorPart.java:190)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:241)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:211)
>   at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.editors.HTMLEditor.sash_createAndAddDesignSourcePage(HTMLEditor.java:269)
>   at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.editors.HTMLEditor.createPages(HTMLEditor.java:440)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:348)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:289)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2863)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2768)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2760)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2711)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2707)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2691)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu.openEditor(OpenWithMenu.java:331)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu$2.handleEvent(OpenWithMenu.java:179)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
>   at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
>   at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
>   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
>   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)

I think I am forgetting something in installation process. Can anyone help here please Thanks in Advance !!

**EDIT:** Solved this error when I deleted files:

> org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui.source_1.1.601.v201108151912.jar
>   org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui_1.1.601.v201108151912.jar

and downloaded:

> org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui.source_1.1.401.v200908111935.jar
>   org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui_1.1.401.v200908111935.jar

But now I lost complete support of JSP from Eclipse.
[Refer this for more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839012/jsp-support-in-eclipse-with-crystal-reports-plugin)

Comment: What *was* the installation process?  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError almost always means a broken installation.

Comment: @nitind- I used this link for installation process:http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-29757

Comment: @nitind-Eclipse Update Manager specifically.

Comment: @nitind-I suspect that some file is missing somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this error when I uninstalled following plug-ins from Help->About Eclipse SDK->Installation Details:

- Android DDMS, Android Development Tools, Android Hierarchy Viewer,
  Android Traceview.
- Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
- JST Web UI,etc...

And then again Re-installed them.

Finally I got JSP support on Crystal Reports(.rpt) files as well as complete Android support on Eclipse.