# JSP support in Eclipse With Crystal Reports Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, crystal-reports, eclipse-3.6

I want to generate a JSP file in eclipse helios-SR2-win32 (3.6) version. It should be as simple as **right-clicking on the Web Content folder of the Crystal Reports Web Project and selecting New->JSP**, but some how I dont have the option of **JSP** inside *New*. I also downloaded the "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers", because it could be one of the reasons for this error, but still nothing.

**Ideally it should be like::**

[image]

I found this problem when I was finding the JSP editor, for which I downloaded Eclipse Web Page editor [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1438909/1465910). Before that I had the *New->JSP* option (although I am not sure about it).

I am generating Crystal Reports with help of Eclipse, so I can get JSP files from Report files(.rpt). But I want to generate in above mentioned way. I think its linked with some jar file missing, and so searched for a long time on Google but found no solution.

Please help me by some links or guidance.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What options show up when you right click on your Crystal Reports Web Project and then New ?

Comment: @HardikMishra-It shows all the options like Project, File, Folder, sql File, etc that we have on New, but not JSP..

Comment: @HardikMishra-I also downloaded the "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this error when I uninstalled following plug-ins from Help->About Eclipse SDK->Installation Details:

- Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
- JST Web UI

And then again Re-installed them by Help->Install New Software.
Help -> Install new Software, choose the `Helios - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios` and in that `Web, XML, and Java EE Development->Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools AND JST Web UI` and press Next and finally Finish.